# How do I tell Upstart to run a script before shutting down any service?

Tags: shutdown, upstart

I want to be able to tell upstart to run a certain script linked under `/etc/rc0.d/K99-somescript` to run before any of the services such as **Nginx, PHP-fpm** are shutdown.